# Gitlab Pipeline shows wrong status

Tags: gitlab-ci

in `.gitlab-ci.yml` I am using `trigger` to use different CI configurations.

When running a pipeline, it shows the status as passed even that the downstream pipeline failed.

example:

[image]

How can I make the pipeline status to display failed when the downstream pipeline is failing?

Comment: Do you have an exit code in your script if the stage fails `exit 1`?

Comment: yes. `ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1`

Comment: Do you want CI shell runner to fail the build and not proceed to the next stage?

Comment: the current behaviour that it is failing and not proceeding to the next stage. I want to keep it like this. I am just confused by the status of the "whole" pipeline as it states "passed" while it is not.